# Where is the information written to when you execute `chflags hidden` command for a folder in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, folders

Does the `chflags hidden` shell command write information to the folder itself, or write it to another hidden file like `.DS_Store`? I'd like to know because I'm making a thumb drive and I'd like to remove any extra files that show up on older versions of Windows. I don't want to remove the property of the folder being hidden on macOS, OS X, and newer versions of Windows.

Comment: The chflags just writes filesystem data for one file. What filesystem are you choosing on the thumb drive? How the metadata is stored might affect the answer.

Comment: ExFAT filesystem